# how to optimize nested for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I have a for loop nested thrice in a matlab program. Can any of you help me optimize it.

```
w=5;
a = rand(m*n,10); b=rand(m,n);
for i = 1 : m
   for j = 1 : n
      for k = 1 : l
         if (i-w >= 1 && i+w <= m)
             featureL = a(((i-1)*n)+j,:); featureR = a(((i-1)*n)+j-d,:);
             D1(i,j,k) = sqrt( sum( (featureL - featureR) .* (featureL - featureR) ) );
             D2(i,j,k) = mean2( b(i-w:i+w, j-w:j+w) );
         end
      end
   end
end
```

I know the performance could be heavily improved by using meshgrid, but I am not sure how to  do it.

Thanks in anticipation.

Can it be done something like this..

```
[X Y Z] = meshgrid(1:m,1:n,1:l);
D1(something containing X,Y,Z) = sqrt( sum( ( a(something cont. X,Y) - a(something cont. X,Y)).*(a(something cont. X,Y) - a(something cont. X,Y)) ) );
% similarly D2
```

Thanks a lot!.

Comment: Not a full answer but a quick hint to begin: avoid the if-statement by modifying the most-outter loop like this: `for i=1+w:m-w`.

Comment: Can you specify the values of `m`, `n`, `l` and `d` that you're working with?

Comment: @Bentoy13 this is certainly a first improvement. Also i don't see any influence of `k` on the calculations. As far as I can see all pages are the same -> use `repmat`.

Comment: Always good for optimization - the output of `mlint your_file_name` It gives lots of warnings you should preallocate D1 and D2.

Comment: @raghudeep: I suspect you have a typo: what is the value of `d`? is it the same as `w`? also how are the formulas depending on `k`? Please double check your code..

Answer (score 2):

I've found that a good way to attack these things is incrementally. Start by examining everything in the innermost loop, and see if it can be done at a higher level. This will reduce repeated computations.

For example, you can perform your `if (i-w >= 1 && i+w <= m)` two levels higher (since it only depends on `i`,`w`, and `m`), reducing if checks and skipping loop iterations. 
Once that is done, your `featureL` and `featureR` calculations can be moved up one level; they are performed inside the `k` loop but only depend on `j`. Similarly, `sqrt( sum( (featureL - featureR) .* (featureL - featureR) ) )` can be computed outside of the `k` loop, put into a variable, and assigned later.

In fact, as far as I can see you can get rid of the entire `k` loop since `k` is never used. Here's your code with some of this applied:

```
w=5; 
a = rand(m*n,10); 
b=rand(m,n); 
for i = 1 : m
    if (i-w >= 1 && i+w <= m)
        for j = 1 : n
            featureL = a(((i-1)*n)+j,:); 
            featureR = a(((i-1)*n)+j-d,:);
            x = sqrt( sum( (featureL - featureR) .* (featureL - featureR) ) );
            y = mean2( b(i-w:i+w, j-w:j+w) )           
            D1(i,j,:) = x;              
            D2(i,j,:) = y;
        end    
    end 
end
```

Comment: Only one more thing, in this code you are iterating from 1 to m, but the if condition does that the real valid values were from i+w (6 in your code) to m-w. Then you can redefine the for i range and delete the if condition.